# Term for simplest possible description of problem

Tags: discussion, terminology

I'm looking for the term that people use to describe the simplest statement of a problem. I've seen it several times on Meta and on SO.

[If you think this question is inappropriate, please answer it in a COMMENT so I can still delete the question.]

Comment: tl;dr...   too long;didn't read

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're looking for the term "SSCCE":

[Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

This is pretty much a prerequisite for any SO debugging question that isn't obvious to spot.